# how should "...; or ..." be understood?

Tags: meaning, grammar, semicolons

I'm trying to make sense of a phrase like the following

> The foregoing limitations shall not apply to ... [A] ...; or, subject to the provisions of ... [B] ... , to ... [C] ... .

(The actual text is [Article IX § 6](http://legislature.mi.gov/doc.aspx?mcl-Article-IX-6) of the Michigan constitution.)

In particular, the grammar around "; or,".  Would it be correct to write the long sentence as two separate sentences, removing "; or,"?  That is,

> The foregoing limitations shall not apply to ... [A] ... . The foregoing limitations shall not apply, subject to the provisions of ... [B] ... , to ... [C] ... .

Does the text after "; or," influence the meaning; in particular "subject to the provisions of ..."?

Or are these really not grammar questions, *per se*, in that there isn't necessarily a "right" answer and this is why we have lawyers (and judges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The passage](http://www.legislature.mi.gov/(S(wm4lwk55epjsoy55fp2lehaf))/mileg.aspx?page=GetObject&objectname=mcl-Article-IX-6) has a structure to it. You can read it as follows:

> - All taxes of a certain kind are subject to the following limits: (1), (2), and (3).
> - These limits don't apply in any of the following cases:
>
>   - (X);
>   - (Y), subject to the provisions of (another law Z which interacts with this one).

That is, (X) and (Y) are independent -- the limits on the taxes don't apply when *either* (X) or (Y) are true.

I probably wouldn't write two separate sentences, because using "The foregoing limitations..." right after another instance of itself might be confusing. Bullets or a hierarchical structure would do a better job of conveying the meaning, I think.